# EntityFramework - nova tabela não foi criada

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Seguindo este [tutorial](http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-1/) foram criadas as tabelas tudo certinho.

Depois fui fazer um teste, criei uma nova entidade, fiz o `update-database` e nada de criar a tabela no SQL Server 2012. Fiz algumas alterações na entidade, adicionei *migrations*, tentei fazer um update novamente, mas não cria a tabela de jeito nenhum.

```
namespace Domain.entities
{
    public class teste
    {
        public teste() {
            teste t = new teste();
            t.idade = 15;
        }
        public int testeId { get; set; }
        public int idade { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace DataAccess.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class teste : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.teste",
                c => new
                    {
                        testeId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.testeId);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.teste");
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace DataAccess.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class teste4 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.teste", "nome", c => c.String(maxLength: 100, unicode: false));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.teste", "nome");
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(): base("DataContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Turma> Turmas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Professor> Professores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<teste> Testes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Properties()
                   .Where(p => p.Name == p.ReflectedType.Name + "Id")
                   .Configure(p => p.IsKey());

            modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                   .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("varchar"));

            modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                  .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(100));
        }
    }
}
```

Por que não cria a tabela "teste"?

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" 
         connectionString="Server=DW; Database=EFEscola; uid=sa; password=123456;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Você tá olhando no banco certo? Já conferiu a connection string?

Comment: Sim, até porque eu não fiz nenhuma modificação de banco, terminei o tutorial e já fiz esse teste.

Comment: Faça um select na tabela `__MigrationHistory` e veja qual o último `MigrationId`

Comment: Tem apenas um: 201708181156480_AutomaticMigration

Comment: Bem, então isso quer dizer que você **não está usando** migrations no seu projeto. Ou seja, a atualização é feita sempre rodando apenas `Update-Database`. Não adianta criar migration porque o EF não vai tentar usá-la. Apague o arquivo de migration e execute um `Update-Database` no console.

Comment: Apaguei algumas classes de migration que tinha lá, ficou somente uma "Configuration.cs". Fiz o update-database e me retornou isso aqui: Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.

Comment: E o banco foi alterado? Aliás, você tá atualizando o SSMS pra verificar as modificações, né?

Comment: Não criou a tabela. Sim, atualizo o banco pra ver. Uma pergunta, quando eu habilito {AutomaticMigrationsEnabled} não pode mais criar migrations basta apenas usar o update-database?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Aparentemente você começou de um jeito e partiu pra outro. Se eu fosse você, testaria com outro banco.

Comment: criei outro banco, exclui a pasta migrations, habilitei outra, mas agora nenhuma tabela foi criada. Será que ele não está usando o SQL Server? Estranho, porque eu não modifiquei a string de conexão que havia dado certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema, a `connectionString` estava só no `App.config` do DataAccess, coloquei no Console e resolveu. Mais uma vez foi um problema com connectionString.

Answer (score 1):

Muitas vezes é necessário que seja apagado os arquivos de [migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx) e recompilar o projeto e executar novamente o `Update-Database`.

Algumas vezes também é necessário que se user o `Update-Database -Force`

Para ver o que foi executado use o `-Verbose`, `Update-Database -Force -Verbose`

Lembre de alterar na sua classe `Configuration` o `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` deixe como `true`.

Veja [como usar Entity Framework Migrations](https://imasters.com.br/framework/dotnet/como-usar-entity-framework-migrations/?trace=1519021197&source=single).

Comment: Veja: 'PM> Update-Database -Force -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'Console'.
Using NuGet project 'DataAccess'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'DataContext' (DataSource: (localdb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.'

Comment: Desculpa, mas como faço pra colocar aqui como um trecho de código, me refiro à formatação. Vou postar o App.config no meu post.

Comment: Clique no ajuda ao lado use ` para abri e fecha ... você esta executando isso no projeto Console. é nele mesmo que esta seu EF ?

Comment: Estou executando os comandos no DataAccess onde está o DataContext. Não seria um problema de comunicação com o SQL Server?

Comment: O que seria `DataSource` e `(localdb)\v11.0` ?

Answer (score -2):

Eu estava com problemas pois eu fazia todos os passo corretos porém o Entity Framework Core 7 não criava Tabela no Banco de Dados Azure SQL Server. Quebrei a cabeça um tempo e a única coisa que funcionou foi usar primeiro o comando

add-migration InitialCreate
E depois:
Update-Database

Vou deixar registrado caso alguem passe por isso.